# How to replace '\' while keep '\n'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this data:

```
bytesObj = b'{"a":1,"b":"test","c":"\xfc\\\\\xba\xda\\n123"}'
tmpStr = bytesObj.decode('gb18030','ignore')
tmpStr
{"a":1,"b":"test","c":"黒\\黑\\n123"}
```

What I have try:

```
import re
b = re.sub(r'\\', '', tmpStr)
```

Then I got:

```
{"a":1,"b":"test","c":"黒黑n123"}
```

My expected output:

```
{"a":1,"b":"test","c":"黒黑\n123"}
```

Can u help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by excluding `n` after `\`.

```
b = re.sub(r'\\(?!n)', '', tmpStr)
```

That results in:

```
{"a":1,"b":"test","c":"黒黑\n123"}
```

You can also use a collection of characters by using the `|` pipe symbol. In the following `\n` and `\x` are ignored.

```
b = re.sub(r'\\(?!n|x)', '', tmpStr)
```

**Addendum**

```
(?!     look ahead operator
```

Comment: Thank u, x is any characters I can change?

Comment: Correct, I adjusted my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can ditch reg ex too.

```
newStr = ''
for index, char in enumerate(tmpStr):
  if char == '\\' and tmpStr[index+1] != 'n': 
    newStr += ''
  else:
    newStr += tmpStr[index]
print(newStr)
```